# iOS - UILabel(CALayer) - VMalloc memory keep increasing

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, interface-builder

I used Instrument to test my app with 2 `ViewController`s that go forth and back with button via `segue`. I noticed that all of my `UILabel` in `ViewController1`(created using Interface Builder) keep adding up my memory allocation every time I go to `ViewController1`. Is there somewhere in the setting that I can set so that it will deallocate or at least not growing?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting all your UILabels to nil on the dealloc method.

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    self.mYLabel = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: I am using `ARC`, so I do not have `dealloc`.